# How can I parse JSON string with new Date() and get a Date property in the object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Does anyone know how can I get `MyDate` property with an actual `Date` object after parsing?

```
var myObject = JSON.parse('{ "MyDate" : new Date ("2013-12-13"), "Test" : "TestString"}');
```

I have a file with thousands of records in JSON and I'm importing it with NodeJS

```
var content = require('./content.json');
```

It would be awesome if someone knows a trick like special quotation marks or something.

In both cases I get this exception:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e
    at Object.parse (native)
    at repl:1:6
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface. (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
```

Comment: That's not valid json. The error must be corrected on the server-side, or whatever generated that json string. `Date` objects are not natively handled by json (in the way that integers, strings, and boolean values are) so perhaps the most portable way is to use the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 and then pass that to `new Date()` when converting to a `Date` object.

Comment: pass the under-used 2nd argument to JSON.parse, reviver(), a function that will find and parse Date data into Date objects. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Example.3A_Using_the_reviver_parameter

Comment: @dandavis Excellent suggestion, you should post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious, where is that JSON is coming from? There is no standard to represent dates, so such extensions might be interesting.

Anyway, this is not a classic JSON. There are dozens of different JSON flavors, but it doesn't look like anything I know of. It doesn't mean that your format is bad, but it does mean that standard JSON.parse will not work here.

However, you can parse it using YAML parser, in which case that Date will be represented as a string which you can replace later.

This is how you can deal with this format:

```
var YAML = require('js-yaml')
var object = YAML.safeLoad('{ "MyDate" : new Date ("2013-12-13"), "Test" : "TestString"}')

function parse_dates(v) {
  if (typeof(v) === 'object') {
     for (var i in object) {
        v[i] = parse_dates(v[i])
     }
  } else if (typeof(v) === 'string') {
     var m = v.match(/^new Date\s*\(["'](.*)["']\)$/)
     if (m != null) {
        return new Date(m[1])
     }
  }
  return v
}

console.log(parse_dates(object))
```

Result:

```
$ TZ=UTC node test.js 
{ MyDate: Fri Dec 13 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  Test: 'TestString' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
var myObject = JSON.parse('{ "MyDate" : "'+new Date ("2013-12-13")+'", "Test" : "TestString"}');
```

Comment: I am guessing that he can't do that because the string comes from somewhere.

Comment: let's see what his limitations are. I think he's building those himself.

Comment: Nothing special that I'm aware of, you can also just put it after  
myObject.MyDate = new Date ("2013-12-13");

Answer (score 0):

As the Wikipedia says, JSON supports some JavaScript native datatypes and some others not:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Unsupported_native_data_types

So I can't do what I want in the way that I want but it's not so important. I can use strings and later somewhere format it.

Thank you for your help!